# How to update MySQL table with a cumulative count of events with the same date

Tags: mysql

I have a table which I pull data from. This data has a date and a stock symbol. There can be multiple rows of data with the same date and different stock symbols. I need to update the table so that there is a running total for all rows with the same date. When a new date occurs the cumulative count re-sets to 1 and then resumes.

A typical query:

```
mysql> SELECT Sym 'sym' ,  fdate as 'FilledDate',  TsTradeNum 'numT'
-> FROM trades_entered_b2
-> WHERE fDate >= '2009-08-03' AND fDate <= '2009-08-07'
-> LIMIT 10;


+------+------------+------+
| sym  | FilledDate | numT |
+------+------------+------+
| WAT   | 2009-08-03 |    0 |
| ALGN  | 2009-08-04 |    0 |
| POT   | 2009-08-05 |    0 |
| PTR   | 2009-08-06 |    0 |
| SCHW  | 2009-08-06 |    0 |
| FDO   | 2009-08-07 |    0 |
| NBL   | 2009-08-07 |    0 |
| RRC   | 2009-08-07 |    0 |
| WAT   | 2009-08-08 |    0 |
| COCO  | 2009-08-08 |    0 |
+------+------------+------+
```

What I want:

```
+------+------------+------+
| sym  | FilledDate | numT |
+------+------------+------+
| WAT   | 2009-08-03 |    1 |
| ALGN  | 2009-08-04 |    1 |
| POT   | 2009-08-05 |    1 |
| PTR   | 2009-08-06 |    1 |
| SCHW  | 2009-08-06 |    2 |
| FDO   | 2009-08-07 |    3 |
| NBL   | 2009-08-07 |    4 |
| RRC   | 2009-08-07 |    5 |
| WAT   | 2009-08-08 |    1 |
| COCO  | 2009-08-08 |    2 |
+------+------------+------+
```

What I need to do is update the TsTradeNum column with the correct values. I have tried to create a function and various queries all failed.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you're trying to do?  It seems like you're trying to assign some kind of serial number to each row within each day.  Are you trying to do this after the table is populated, or as you first insert the rows into the table? Also please keep in mind that rows in a table don't have any implicit order. If you're doing this after the fact, how do you know which row gets which `numT` value?

Comment: couldn't you use an auto incremented insertion trigger that gets reset every day?  Otherwise this looks similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207267/update-increment-a-single-column-on-multiple-rows-at-once)

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing this after the fact. What I am trying to do is serially count the number of times a certain events occur on the same date. Here:  
From trades_entered_b2 WHERE tfamt = 3 AND tsamt <> 0

Answer (score 0):

Could try below.The query will increment numT by 1 if the previous row date is same with current row, else it will reset numT to 1.

```
SELECT sym, FilledDate, numT  
FROM(
SELECT sym, FilledDate,
   @count:=CASE WHEN ( @date <> FilledDate) THEN 1 
                ELSE 
                    @count+1                     
                END AS numT,
    @date:=FilledDate as dlset        
FROM
(SELECT @count:= -1) s,
(SELECT @date:= -1) d,    
  (SELECT id, sym, FilledDate
   FROM mytable3  
   ORDER BY FilledDate,sym desc        
  ) t ) a
```