# updating a column value in sql that start from last row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table having column name ID(primary key).

in this I have values from 1 to 152.

now I want to update the table so that the id ranging from 109 to 152 incremented by 1.

when I run this sql

```
 update category set id=(id+1) where id<152 and id>108
```

it give error because when it update ID=109 to 110 then it found duplicate of 110 in next row.

so how can I do that.

can I start updating from last row that is 152 and stop it on 108.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: If you already have values between `109` and `152` in your table before updating, and `id` is a primary key, there`s no way you can perform the update, unless you delete the possible duplicate values before updating. Besides that, make up your mind and/or tell us which RDBMS are you using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using MySQL.  If so, you can do this by using `order by`.

```
update category
    set id = id + 1
    where id > 108 and id < 152
    order by id desc;
```

Assuming the `id`s are positive, the following should work in any database (assuming the column is not declared "unsigned"):

```
update category
    set id = -(id + 1)
    where id > 108 and id < 152;

update category
    set id = -id
    where id < 0;
```

Comment: @SunilKumar - FYI, SQL server executes your original query as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps. First add 10,000 (or any other unused range) and then subtract 9999. Do not forget to adjust the criteria in the second step.