# Ranking based on users placement instead of score

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, logic

I have a issue that I cannot wrap my head around.

I am using the Laravel Framework.

I am trying to make a ranking table based on placement (Meaning the user does not have any SCORE, they just have placements)

How I want it to work is the following way:

**User A** = Placement: 1

**User B** = Placement: 10

**User B** wins over **User A**, then **User B** gets placed as **number 1** and **User A** gets placed as **number 2**, and then I want it to update all the other users accordingly.

I can't seem to find a reliable way of doing this.

Comment: You mean with all that Laravel magic it won't do it for you? I'm just horsing around. You're just going to have to do an update to the database rows. Maybe instead of placement you could do percentage. It would be a lot easier.

Comment: @BrianGottier I am not sure I follow, I don't know what u mean by doing it with percentages instead. The placement is essentially the rank of the user. If I were to update the rank of the winner and the loser, then there would be a duplicate (Two users with the same rank) - How could I avoid that?

Comment: Actually, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207267/update-increment-a-single-column-on-multiple-rows-at-once , and imagine a where clause in there. You can also subtract in the query. Shouldn''t be that hard to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a Laravel challenge but an SQL one. And it may be simple to solve: basically, you will ask for the actual position of the defeated person, if the position is greater than the winner, you do nothing, otherwise you will assign the position of the loser to the new winner and update the rest of the table with a +1 in the position column.

In code it would be something like this:

```
$winner_player = User::where('id', userA->id)->first();
$loser_player = User::where('id', userB->id)->first();

if($winner_player->position < $loser_player->position) {
     //Update the rest of the users. 
     //We add 2 because we need space for the new winner and for 
     //the loser that is still above of the rest of the players. 
     DB::table('users')
        ->where('position', '>', $loser_player->position)
        ->update(DB::raw('position+2'));

     //Set the winner with the actual position of the loser.
     $winner_player->position = $loser_player->position;
     $winner_player->save();

     //Set the looser with the new position (+1 of his actual).
     $loser_player->position = $loser_player->position + 1; 
     $loser_player->save();
}
```

**UPDATED LOGIC**
As Classified pointed out, it moves the rows around but doesn't do it correctly, so I'm updating the logic to make it work as it is supposed to, and it will be a little simpler too.

```
$winner_player = User::where('id', userA->id)->first();
$loser_player = User::where('id', userB->id)->first();

if($winner_player->position < $loser_player->position) {
     //Set the winner with the actual position of the loser.
     $winner_player->position = $loser_player->position;

     //Update the users between the swap. There is no need to update 
     //the whole table, we only update the records between the swap.
     DB::table('users')
        ->where([['position', '<', $winner_player->position],
                 ['position', '>=', $loser_player->position]])
        ->update(DB::raw('position+1'));

     //Save the value of the winner AFTER updating the positions 
     //between winner and loser.
     $winner_player->save();
}
```

Comment: I'll definetly try this tommorow, and see how it goes. I'll comment once I've tried and tested it.

Comment: This fixed the underlying issue. However this does not work correctly if there are only three users, then if the 2nd ranked user gets moved to 1st then the 3rd place will be 5th.

Comment: You are correct!!! I ran the logic under the assumption that all the records had to be updated, but actually, the records that need to be updated are those between the position swap. I've updated my answer with the newly proposed logic, let me know if that works for you!!