# Moving users on a ranking table based on placement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, logic

Code is based on what Lvkz [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45944585/ranking-based-on-users-placement-instead-of-score/45945482#45945482) on my previous question, and it solved the bigger issue I was having. However I need help finding a way to avoid duplicates and just faulty number sequences.

```
$winner_ranking = $winner->getRankings()->where('ranklist_id', $ranklist_id)->first();
$loser_ranking = $loser->getRankings()->where('ranklist_id', $ranklist_id)->first();

if ($winner_ranking->placement > $loser_ranking->placement) {
    $rankings = ClubRanking::where('placement', '>', $loser_ranking->placement)
        ->where('ranklist_id', '=', $ranklist_id)
        ->increment('placement', 2);

    $winner_ranking->placement = $loser_ranking->placement;
    $winner_ranking->save();

    $loser_ranking->placement = $loser_ranking->placement + 1;
    $loser_ranking->save();
}
```

**User A** = Placement: 1

**User B** = Placement: 2

If **User B** wins over **User A** then the number sequence will look as follows

> **User B** = Placement: 1
>
> **User A** = Placement: 2
>
> **User C** = Placement: 4
>
> **User D** = Placement: 5
>
> **User E** = Placement: 6

Also a **quick note**, the issue still **persists** but in a different way if I were to change the **increment** to 1 instead of 2.

Comment: What is `$ranklist_id`?

Comment: $ranklist_id is a GET route parameter, so essentially it's just the ID of the ranklist where we want to change stuff. (To clarify: There are several ranklists.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hasn't been tested but if I understand what you're after it should give you want you want:

```
if ($winner_ranking->placement > $loser_ranking->placement) {

    $rankings = ClubRanking::whereBetween('placement', [$loser_ranking->placement, $winner_ranking->placement])
        ->where('id', '!=', $winner_ranking->id)
        ->where('ranklist_id', '=', $ranklist_id)
        ->increment('placement');

    $winner_ranking->placement = $loser_ranking->placement;
    $winner_ranking->save();

}
```

Comment: the whereNot function kept giving a column error, so I just changed it to where('id', '!=', $winner_ranking->id) instead, and that worked perfectly. Cheers.